# Putting data from two tables into one ViewData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, selectlist, viewdata

I'm trying to put data from two tables (`AcademicDegrees`, `Lecturers`) connected by one to many relations into one `ViewData` to generate options to field (with label and id as value). It should be something like this where IDs are used as values and another field as the label.

```cs
ViewData["ClassroomsId"] = new SelectList(_context.Classroom, "ClassroomsID", "Number");
```

When all the data for the field was in one table I used the getter form field to get it.

```cs
[NotMapped]
public string toStringVar => FirstName + " " + LastName;
```

When I added table with academic degrees I moved to a different solution.

```cs
var lecturers = _context.Lecturer;
var degree = _context.AcademicDegrees;
var lecturersList = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach (Lecturers l in lecturers)
{
    _context.AcademicDegrees.Where(d => d.AcademicDegreeId == l.AcademicDegreesId).Load();
    foreach(AcademicDegrees d in degree)
    {
        lecturersList.Add(new SelectListItem(
                  $"{d.Name} {l.FirstName} {l.LastName}", l.LecturersID.ToString()
             ));
        }
    }

ViewData["LecturersId"] = new SelectList(lecturersList);
```

The problem is that it isn't interpreted as I want it to be.

[image: result]

I also can't put it directly into `SelectList` because it doesn't have an empty constructor or add method. Is there any other way to implement a `SelectList`?

Comment: Can't u just join the table using Linq on the select list query?

Comment: Better still: use navigation properties, don't join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it is like *redundant work* as you have the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` instance which can be used to build the select option.

And you pass `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` instance to create the `SelectList` instance.

Would suggest to pass `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` value to ViewData.

**Solution for `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`**

> Controller

```cs
ViewData["LecturersId"] = lecturersList;
```

> View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model./*YourProperty*/, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["LecturersId"])
```

**Updated**

Since you are using ASP.NET Core MVC, with tag helper:

```
<select asp-for="/*YourProperty*/" 
    asp-items="@((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["LecturersId"]))">
</select>
```

---

**Solution for `SelectList`**

If you are keen on the `SelectList`, make sure that you have provided the `dataValueField` and `dataTextField` according to this [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-selectlist-ctor(system-collections-ienumerable-system-string-system-string))

```cs
public SelectList (System.Collections.IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField);
```

as below:

```cs
ViewData["LecturersId"] = new SelectList(lecturersList, "Value", "Text");
```

---

Besides, the query part would be suggested to optimize by joining both tables as below:

```cs
var lecturersList = (from a in _context.Lecturer
    join b in _context.AcademicDegrees on a.AcademicDegreeId equals b.AcademicDegreeId
    select new SelectListItem($"{b.Name} {a.FirstName} {a.LastName}", a.LecturersID.ToString())
).ToList();
```